# WGCNA : Choosing a soft-threshold power

Tags: r, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, bioconductor

`powers = c(c(1:10), seq(from = 12, to=20, by=2));`

While going through WGCNA i came across this code which i am not able to understand, can anybody explain me the meaning of that piece of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code will create a vector of numbers stored in `powers`.

Specifically: `1:10` creates the numbers `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` (can read as 1 through 10) and `seq(from = 12, to = 20, by = 2)` creates a sequence of every other number from 12 to 20, i.e. `12 14 16 18 20`.

Powers will contain the following 15 numbers: `1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 12 14 16 18 20`

I am not familiar with the `WGCNA`package or if `powers` is an argument to a function, but this is what `powers` contains.